# How to mock elastic search python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, elasticsearch

I need to mock elasticsearch calls, but I am not sure how to mock them in my python unit tests. I saw this framework called `ElasticMock`. I tried using it the way indicated in the documentation and it gave me plenty of errors.
It is here : 
https://github.com/vrcmarcos/elasticmock

My question is, is there any other way to mock elastic search calls?

This doesn't seem to have an answer either: [Mock elastic search data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084131/mock-elastic-search-data).
And this just indicates to actually do integration tests rather than unit tests, which is not what I want:
[Unit testing elastic search inside Django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128632/unit-testing-elastic-search-inside-django-app).

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have never mocked things with `ElasticSearch`.

Comment: How are you calling ES in code? WHy not make a "data acess" class with some methods you can mock out easily? It's not clear to me what problems you are having.

Comment: I have a class, and through that class I have some methods that try to store data on ES. I want to mock out the ES part. Could you elaborate on what you meant?

Comment: My code tries to really access ES, how can I substitute that?

Comment: Send in ES - then you can send in something else in the tests.

Comment: I get that , but my question is how do I do that?

Answer (score 6):

You have to mock the attr or method you need, for example:

```
import mock

with mock.patch("elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search") as mocked_search, \
                mock.patch("elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create") as mocked_index_create:

            mocked_search.return_value = "pipopapu"
            mocked_index_create.return_value = {"acknowledged": True}
```

In order to know the path you need to mock, just explore the lib with your IDE. When you already know one you can easily find the others.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to give a very abstract answer because this applies to more than ES.

```
class ProductionCodeIWantToTest:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def do_something(data):
    es = ES() #or some database or whatever
    es.post(data) #or the right syntax
```

Now I can't test this.
With one small change, injecting a dependency:

```
class ProductionCodeIWantToTest:
  def __init__(self, database):
    self.database = database

  def do_something(data):
    database.save(data) #or the right syntax
```

Now you can use the real db:

```
es = ES() #or some database or whatever
thing = ProductionCodeIWantToTest(es)
```

or test it

```
mock = #... up to you - just needs a save method so far
thing = ProductionCodeIWantToTest(mock)
```

Comment: Ok, so what you are saying is that I need to change my original code in order to mock elastic search? So if I call mock argument I just return dummy things from my own code? But isnt the purpose of mocking to test my original code without modifying it? This looks like I need to modify my existing code, let me know if I understood it wrong.

Comment: In theory you can use thier decorator - but I think this approach makes your life easier, and the code more flexible. You asked if there was another way to mock the calls. If you want to use your existing code and their decorator I suggest starting a new question inlucindg your code and the specific errors you are getting.

Answer (score 4):

After looking at the decorator source code, the trick for me was to reference Elasticsearch with the module:

```
import elasticsearch
...
elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(...
```

instead of

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
...
Elasticsearch(...
```